# Generate embed PDF file using CodeIgniter and mPDF library

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, web, mpdf

I would get something like this:
http://tekdi.net/demoz/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=65&Itemid=34

I already managed to generate a pdf file on a new page, but I was interested in getting it generated within a page so you can see the header, menus, etc.

I am using **CodeIgniter** and **mPDF** library.

Sorry if my English is not very good. I am Spanish and I have not much experience with English. Thank you very much to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to generate a PDF file using mPDF, then view it using some sort of a viewer like this [one](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js)